# multiprocessing.set_start_method() not available with Python 3.4?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

The python [dev docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#start-methods) for the multiprocessing module seems to indicate that multiprocessing.set_start_method() should exist as of python 3.4. I installed python 3.4a1 on Mac OS X (10.8.4) via the installer, but when I do:

```
import multiprocessing
multiprocessing.set_start_method('forkserver')
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set_start_method'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python 3.4a1 is - as the `a` indicates - still an alpha version. Not all features the final version will have are already implemented.

Specifically, this feature was [added on Wed, 14 Aug 2013](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/3b82e0d83bf9). The alpha was released on Sat, 3 August 2013.